# ERROR at line 1: ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Tags: oracle

```
create table student(id int,name varchar2(20),marks int);
insert into student(id,name,marks) values(545,"wiahr",100);
```

or

```
insert into student values(545,"wiahr",100);
```

For the above two insertions, I am getting the following error

> insert into student(id,name,marks) values(545,"wiahr",100)
>                                                 * ERROR at line 1: ORA-00984: column not allowed here

can you please help with this.

Comment: please confirm that you are  using mysql

Comment: The error message suggests an Oracle database, not MySQL.

Comment: [Repro via fiddle with Oracle 18c](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=87afa489b5d848f622331c7e0e316dad)

Comment: are you sure this code is not inside others string and you have a worng string closing sequence ??

Answer (score 1):

Per the error message, you're actually using an Oracle database, and with Oracle databases [strings should be encapsulated by *single* quotes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm):

```
insert into student(id,name,marks) values(545,'wiahr',100);
```

#### ([live demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bf67c095b0fb09b81543ace01daddf3f))

Double quotes instead [name fields](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223) (and fields are invalid in the `VALUES` clause of an `INSERT` statement).

It's specifically called out in the [`INSERT` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems025.htm):

> Character and date literals in the `VALUES` list must be enclosed by single quotes (`'`). Numeric literals are not enclosed by quotes.

This is in contrast to MySQL, with which you can use either single- or double-quotes for strings, and *backticks* introduce fields.

Answer (score 0):

String literals are denoted by single quotes (`'`), not double quotes (`"`):

```
insert into student (id, name, marks) values (545, 'wiahr', 100);
-- Here -------------------------------------------^-----^
```